# Design for ConnectionPool

Tags: java, design-patterns, connection-pooling

When some one asks you to write (do / depict) design for Connection Pool in a Java interview what would you typically write.

Do you write code for connection pool or do you depict the Class diagrams. Can somebody please explain the design of Connection pool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Object Pool pattern (and Connection Pool is a particular case of it) is greatly described in Mark Grand's 'Patterns in Java. Vol. 1'.

Here is a basic class diagram (from google images):

[alt text http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/8448/poolz.png](http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/8448/poolz.png)

Main idea: `Client` shouldn't create `Reusable` objects by himself. Instead of that he should use `ReusablePool`. To get `Reusable` object he should call `acquireReusable`. When he doesn't need `Reusable` object any more he should put it back trough calling `releaseReusable`.

`ReusablePool` contains a list of `Reusable` objects. When `Client` asks for `Reusable`, pool looks for existing free `Reusable`. If all `Reusable` objects are acquired then if list size is less then `maxSize` `ReusablePool` creates one more `Reusable` object. When list size is equals to `maxSize` pool doesn't create new `Reusable`. Instead of that it waits until some other client give him back any `Reusable` object.

From this description you can make 2 conclusions:

1. `Reusable` objects shouldn't have a state (or their state should be 'cleared' in `releaseReusable` method)
2. `ReusablePool` is usually a part of multithreading applications and all synchronization stuff inside all its methods should be implemented in a proper way (and it's not an easy task).